# What is the meaning of 칼고하다?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

I'm playing online game with other korean people, there's 1 word which is 칼고합니다 that they use a lot and I don't understand the meaning of it. I couldn't find any translation on the internet.

Example : 다오셔서  50분칼고합니다

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, the 칼 means sharp.
So the translation of the example is

```
다오셔서 50분칼고합니다.  
=> (모두) 다 오셨기 때문에 50분에 바로 출발합니다.
=> Everybody is gathered, so we will go(or start) at 50 sharp.
```

You can refer to this page
https://www.contextualdictionary.com/translate/korean-english/%EC%B9%BC%EA%B0%99%EC%9D%B4

Comment: I didn't expect that translation, thank you